# How to list all environment variables in a c/c++ app

Tags: c++, c, macos, terminal, environment-variables

I know that when programming in c++ I can access individual environment variables with [`getenv`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/).

I also know that, in the os x terminal, I can list ALL of the current environment variables using [`env`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env).

I'm interested in getting a complete list of the environment variables that are available to my running c++ program. Is there a c/c++ function that will list them? In other words, is there a way to call `env` from my c++ code?

Comment: The magic is here: [env.c](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=OpenSolaris_b135/cmd/env/env.c).

Comment: The shell command is `env`, not `ENV` (I've edited your question to fix that).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `environ` global variable. It is a null-terminated pointer to an array of strings in the format `name=value`. Here's a miniature clone of `env`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern char **environ;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for(char **current = environ; *current; current++) {
        puts(*current);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Indeed.  `man getenv` has at the bottom (on OS X, which the OP mentions) a `SEE ALSO` section which mentions `environ(7)`.  So `man environ` provides a manpage which explains this.  `apropos environment` includes this page, too.  This isn't meant to be RTFM, but a hint to the OP that the `SEE ALSO` sections of manpages can be worth checking.

Answer (score 14):

You may be able to use the non-portable [envp](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html) argument to `main`:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[], char** envp)
```

and as a bonus apparently on `OSX` you have [apple](https://web.archive.org/web/20170816030253/http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2006/02/char-apple-argument-vector.html) which gives you other OS supplied info:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp, char **apple)
```

> But what is it used for? Well, Apple can use the apple vector to pass whatever "hidden" parameters they want to any program. And they do actually use it, too. Currently, apple[0] contains the path where the executing binary was found on disk. What's that you say? How is apple[0] different from argv[0]? The difference is that argv[0] can be set to any arbitrary value when execve(2) is called. For example, shells often differentiate a login shell from a regular shell by starting login shells with the first character in argv[0] being a -

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, I forgot that [`system`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) lets you execute terminal commands.

This snippet gives me what I need:

```
std::cout << "List of environment variables: << std::endl;
system("env");
```

Comment: That doesn't make the variable available to your program, it just prints them to standard output.