# Main function with three arguments

Tags: c

I ran into a function like this earlier:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **argw){


}
```

Why is there a need for three arguments, and how does this actually work?

Comment: Looks related to getting [environment variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765545/how-to-list-all-environment-variables-in-a-c-c-app) some more details would help.

Comment: As I recall, the variable was indeed called envp. Does that mean **argw is not an argument provided from the commandline?

Comment: It is environment variables of your shell in Unix let's says. So it is not provided on the command line and it is not portable. OSX adds a 4th argument `apple`, which I cover in my answer linked above.

Comment: This is *likely* an extension provided by the implementation. It is described in ISO/IEC 9899:201x §J.5.1 Common Extensions: "In a hosted environment, the main function receives a third argument, char *envp[], that points to a null-terminated array of pointers to char, each of which points to a string that provides information about the environment for this execution of the program (5.1.2.2.1)."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The third argument to main is normally called `envp`.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {
```

Many compilers provide a third argument to `main`, but it is not specified in the C standard, so using it is undefined behaviour. If you try to port the code to a platform that doesn't provide a third parameter the program will most likely fail.

[Is char *envp[] as a third argument to main() portable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321435/is-char-envp-as-a-third-argument-to-main-portable)

Comment: More portably, environment variables can be accessed via the `getenv` function, though that requires knowing the name of the variable you want to refer to. In addition, POSIX specifies `extern char **environ;` (which for some reason isn't declared in any header).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen these arguments before. My compiler places them there as well when starting in C++ code. I can tell you for a fact that they are not necessary in C++, although I can't say for sure in C. They look to be slots for a variables to be passed in to the function `int main`. One of type `int`, and two of type `char`. These variables would be passed in, generally by the user at the time the program is executed.

Comment: The second (and optional third) parameters are of type `char**`, not `char`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Unless it's different in C than in C++, that doesn't seem to be the case, as both seem to be `char (variable name)`, where the `**` is part of the variable name. Although, that is odd as it violates the rules of naming variables, unless the compiler sees the `*` as a 'wildcard'.

Comment: It's the same in C and C++. Declaration syntax is a bit odd, but it's based (not entirely consistently) on the principle that declaration follows use. The syntax of `char **argv` is meant to suggest that `**argv` is of type `char`; it follows from that that `argv` is of type `char**`. The variable name is just `argv`; `**` isn't part of the variable name, it's part of the declaration syntax.

Comment: @KeithThompson Odd, but I think I understand. I'm still learning myself, and trying to lend a hand. I'd like to know, is my response indicating they aren't required accurate, or am I off base here?

Comment: In C, the two standard forms are `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. In C++, the first form is `int main()`. Equivalent forms may also be used; for example, as a parameter definition, `char *argv[]` is equivalent to `char **argv`. Implementations may, but need not, support other forms.

Comment: @KeithThompson I see. Thanks for helping me learn new things!