# What is the linkage of `main( )` in g++

Tags: c++, g++

As per ISO_14882_2014's, 3.6.1 Main function [basic.start.main]

`The linkage (3.5) of main is implementation-defined.`

What is its linkage for g++ as g++'s official document does not seem to have this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not directly mentioned in the manual, but in the chapter on "GCC Command Options" we have this:

> `-Wmain` Warn if the type of `main` is suspicious. **`main` should be a function with external
>   linkage**, returning `int`, taking either zero arguments, two, or three arguments of
>   appropriate types. **This warning is enabled by default in C++** and is enabled
>   by either ‘`-Wall`’ or ‘`-Wpedantic`’.

[Emphasis Added]

From this we can infer that the linkage for `main` in this implementation is external.

Comment: Thanks. The above statement says:  

`.....taking either zero arguments, two, or three arguments of appropriate types...`  


But as per the ISO:  

`An implementation shall allow both  
— a function of () returning int and  
— a function of (int, pointer to pointer to char) returning int`  

how we are taking about 3 arguments here?

Comment: Three argument `main` is an extension provided by some compilers. See this post: [Main function with three arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939379/main-function-with-three-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

This is to prevent you from accidentally calling your main function - or writing a 'wrong' main function.

> **The function main shall not be used within a program.** The linkage
>   (3.5) of main is implementation-defined. A program that defines main
>   as deleted or that declares main to be inline, static, or constexpr is
>   ill- formed. The name main is not otherwise reserved.

Comment: The question that I asked is different. Thanks!!