# How many command line arguments are there in the main function of C language?

Tags: c, arguments, command, line

I know for sure that there are two command-line arguments in C -- `argc` and `argv[]`, but while taking an online test, I figured out that there are 3 command line arguments in C. Can someone please explain to me this.

Comment: Your use of the term "command-line arguments" is mildly confusing.  You are probably thinking of "how many arguments are there to the `main()` function?" — in which case you should see [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336) for the details.  Note that Annex J of the standard recognizes a variant `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)`.  Apple provides a fourth parameter, `char **apple`.  Etc.

Comment: You are talking about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909115/are-there-any-other-arguments-that-main-can-accept

Answer (score 0):

As many as you want. `argv[]` is a `char*` array of all of the arguments passed and `argc` is an integer count of the elements in `argv[]`. [Related TutorialsPoint article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments)